# Getting a string array from strings.xml in xamarin Android

Tags: android, arrays, xml, string, xamarin.android

I have a string array in `strings.xml` that looks like this:

```
<string-array name="helpPages">
    <item>Hello, I am DOS-bot, and I will guide you through this game.</item>
    <item>In this game you will learn how to use a computer terminal or console.
          This is an important tool for dealing with technical problems on your computer.</item>
    <item>For the common user, the terminal can be useful for figuring out problems
          related to Internet connectivity, corrupted or damaged files and many more. </item>
  </string-array>
```

And I want to access it in one of my activities.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
String[] pages = GetStringArray(Resource.Array.helpPages);
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is your error ? Or if there's no error, what is the problem ? pages is null ?

Comment: Turns out the IDE just bugged out, it's fine.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this :

String[] pages = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.helpPages);

Answer (score 0):

The question asked about `Xamarin.Android` but the accepted answer syntax is for `Java`, so here is `C#` syntax (*Xamarin way*):

```
var items = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.helpPages);
```

You can access to each item by using `for` or `foreach`. for ex.:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // do whatever you want with item
}
```